# Sum and intersection of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I,J⊂R$ be ideals. Define: 
$I∩J=\{a∈R : a∈I \mbox{ and }a ∈J\}$
$I+J=\{a+b∈R : a∈I, b∈J\}$.

(a) Prove that $I∩J$ and $I+J$ are ideals.

(b) Suppose $R=ℤ$ or $F[x]$, $I=\langle a\rangle$, and $J=\langle b\rangle$. Identify $I∩J$ and $I+J$.

For part (a), a∈I and b∈J. For r∈R, ra∈I and rb∈J. Therefore, ra+rb=r(a+b)∈I+J, so I+J is an ideal. Is this correct for I+J?

Note: For part (b), suppose I= and J=. Now, I∩J and I+J are both principal in ℤ or in F[x].

I need to feed a formula for the generators of these ideals in terms of a and b?

Comment: You need to check they satisfy the defining properties of an ideal. Did you try anything?

Comment: There are a lot of parts to this. What parts do you understand, and what parts are confusing?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking in the second part, when you say "I=, and J=." You might want to [edit] your question to include this information. You should also tell us your thoughts and efforts on the problem so far, so that we may better tailor our answers to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check that the two properties defining ideals holds.

So if $a, b \in I \cap J$, then $a$ and $b$ are both in $I$ and $J$, so, because $I$ and $J$ are ideals, $a +b \in I$ and  $a +b \in J$. Moreover, for $r \in R$, $ra \in I$ and $ra \in J$ because closure under multiplication by elements of $R$ holds in the two ideals, so $ra$ lies in their intersection. Try the same strategy for $I + J$.

I think something is missing in your point (b) in the definition of $I$ and $J$.